# Django Rest API - Can't make a PUT or DELETE Request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, request, django-views

I have a django Rest API and want to make a put request through Flutter or Postman. What ends up happening is that when I make a put request it returns a response (that looks like it changed, printed out) but actually it never really changes. This is my code!

```
class UserProfileView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

class AssignmentView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Assignment.objects.all()
serializer_class = AssignmentSerializer

filter_backends = (
    django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,
    rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter, 
)
filter_fields = ['studyplan']

class UserAssignmentView(AssignmentView):
http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
def get_queryset(self):
    return Assignment.objects.filter(canview__user=self.request.user)

def put(self, request, format=None):
    return Response({'received data': request.data})

def delete(self, request, format=None):
    return Response({'received data': request.data})


class StudyplanView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Studyplan.objects.all()
serializer_class = StudyplanSerializer

class UserStudyplanView(StudyplanView):
def get_queryset(self):
    return Studyplan.objects.filter(canview__user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you override both `put` and `delete` methods and do nothing inside them. Try calling `super()` methods in them:

```
class UserAssignmentView(AssignmentView):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Assignment.objects.filter(canview__user=self.request.user)

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        super().partial_update(request, format)
        return Response({'received data': request.data})

    def delete(self, request, format=None):
        super().destroy(request, format)
        return Response({'received data': request.data})
```

Comment: response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/williamabrahamsson/Desktop/StudiePlus 2.0/studieplus2/studieplus_app/views.py", line 31, in put
    super().put(request, format)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'put'

Comment: @WilliamAbrahamsson I have update the answer. Turns out, that `ModelViewSet` has `partial_update()` and `destroy()` methods, instead of `put()` and `delete()`. See [the DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset).

Comment: can you give an example on how you would do it? I have tried but couldn't figure it out :)